# How to hide a column on mobile in HTML email written in MJML?

Tags: html, email, html-email, mjml, responsive-emails

Is there a way I can hide an `mj-column` on mobile screen?

Here is what I have tried. While media query works on individual element like the `p` element in `mj-text` (successfully changed it to align right on mobile screen), it is not working on `mj-column` (the social elements are still visible on mobile screen).

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/qOsRwzQ-lP

```
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-style>
      @media (max-width:480px) {
        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width:480px) {
        .mobile {
          text-align: right;
        }
      }
    </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-container>
      <mj-section background-color="#eee">
        <mj-column>

          <mj-text>
            <p class="mobile">Title align right on mobile</p>
          </mj-text>

        </mj-column>
        <mj-column css-class="hidden">
            <mj-social font-size="15px" icon-size="30px" mode="horizontal">
              <mj-social-element name="facebook" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Facebook
              </mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element name="google" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Google
              </mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element  name="twitter" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Twitter
              </mj-social-element>
            </mj-social>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
    </mj-container>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

P.S. HTML in email works very differently then that in browser due to the poor support of HTML5 in email clients. (And that's why we need to use langauge like MJML to add in all those hacks for us) Unfortunetly it seems that hiding on mobile is one of those features that while some solution works in the live editor (i.e. browser), it is not working in the actual email. You may need to find some way to send out an actual email to test.

Comment: What email client are you trying to get it to work in? Some don't accept style blocks, e..g Gmail using an IMAP account. In that case, we would have to make it mobile-first

Comment: We can follow this article to construct something of that nature if that's what you want (inline to be display: none, and the a desktop override via media query, with also a mso- fallback for Outlook) https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/advanced-mjml-coding/

Comment: @Nathan It is for commercial use and it needs to be working in all major email client, including but not limited to Gmail. And it seems that I am already using the technique in the link you provide and it is working on `p` in `mj-text` but not on `mj-column`

Comment: If that was the answer you should tick it, not simply upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `!important` to the `display: none`, like so:

```html
<mjml>
      <mj-head>
        <mj-style>
         @media (max-width:480px) {
          .hidden {
          display: none !important;
            }
          }
          @media (max-width:480px) {
          .mobile {
          text-align: right;
           }
          }
       </mj-style>
      </mj-head>
      <mj-body>
        <mj-section background-color="#eee">
          <mj-column>
            <mj-text>
              <p class="mobile">Title align right on mobile</p>
            </mj-text>
          </mj-column>
          <mj-column css-class="hidden">
            <mj-social font-size="15px" icon-size="30px" mode="horizontal">
              <mj-social-element name="facebook"></mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element name="twitter"></mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element name="google"></mj-social-element>
            </mj-social>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
      </mj-body>
    </mjml>
```

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/skE8wuqbeb

**EDIT:**

Full path might do the trick:

```html
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-style>
      @media (max-width:480px) {
        body > div > div > table > tbody > tr > td > div.mj-column-per-50.mj-outlook-group-fix.hidden{
         display: none !important;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width:480px) {
       .mobile {
         text-align: right;
        }
      }
    </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section background-color="#eee">
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text>
          <p class="mobile">Title align right on mobile</p>
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column css-class="hidden">
        <mj-social font-size="15px" icon-size="30px" mode="horizontal">
          <mj-social-element name="facebook"></mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element name="twitter"></mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element name="google"></mj-social-element>
        </mj-social>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/an8DMM_GHH

Comment: You are hiding both `mj-column`. Also, it is not as simply as just checking on inspector. While it is easy to hide it on the live editor, it may not be working across all the email client. (And that's why we need to use MJML on the first place?)

Comment: I've updated my code. I think that the output counts, and the HTML markup won't change.

Comment: I have tried sending out actual email with your setting, but it is not hiding the second column on mobile.

Comment: I've updated my code with the simple: `.hidden { display: none !important; }`. Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Here's the link to the modified code: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/0fs3d4p1ga

Comment: I have tried sending an actual email again and it is still not working.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Give it another try and let me know it helped or not.

Comment: It's not this. .hidden {display: none !important} works on everything except for those email clients that do not support `<style>` blocks, such as Gmail IMAP (there are multiple different Gmail environments, and this one is different from a gmail.com account).

Answer (score 1):

What you want for the best solution is to have it mobile first so that even clients like Gmail IMAP work, with a fallback for Outlook desktops.

We can achieve this with inline="inline" to set display: none on the mobile block, and then override that for desktops with media queries.

```
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
        <mj-style inline="inline"> 
    .hidden {
        display: none !important;
        mso-hide: none; 
    } 
      
    </mj-style> 
    <mj-style>
    @media only screen and (min-width:480px) { 
.hidden { 
    display: inline-block !important;
 }  
}
      @media only screen and (max-width:480px) { 
.mobile { 
    text-align: right !important;
 }  
}
    </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  <mj-body>
      <mj-section background-color="#eee">
        <mj-column>

          <mj-text>
            <p class="mobile">Title align right on mobile</p>
          </mj-text>

        </mj-column>
        <mj-column css-class="hidden">
            <mj-social font-size="15px" icon-size="30px" mode="horizontal">
              <mj-social-element name="facebook" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Facebook
              </mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element name="google" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Google
              </mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element  name="twitter" href="https://mjml.io/">
                Twitter
              </mj-social-element>
            </mj-social>
        </mj-column>
        
      </mj-section>
      <mj-section> 
</mj-section> 
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

Test that here: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/cud21mVa4S

I've tested this on Litmus and it works on all major platforms (Apple mail, outlook desktop, gmail apps ios android and imap, iPhone, outlook apps android and ios, samsung app, and webmails - gmail, outlook.com and yahoo).

Spacing of columns needs tidying but you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `!important` after `display: none` in `.hidden`? like-

```
display: none !important;
```

`'mj-column'` has a atrribute `'display:inline-block'` which needs to be overridden. Adding  `!important` should work.